# Will a ScheduledExecutorService create new threads as needed?

Tags: java, executorservice

I'm using [`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool%28int%29) to create a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), specifying the number of threads like so:

```
int corePoolSize = 42;
ScheduledExecutorService foo = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(corePoolSize);
```

According to the JavaDocs, the `corePoolSize` argument sets

> the number of threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.

Does this mean that this `ExecutorService` implementation may create more than `corePoolSize` threads as needed, similar to a [cached thread pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29)?

Comment: Core pool size: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495659/how-to-create-a-scheduledexecutorservice-bound-by-only-the-cpu-usage

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No.  The correct answer is no, a ScheduledExecutorService will not spawn new threads.

[See answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678021/why-doesnt-scheduledexecutorservice-spawn-threads-as-needed)

Comment: Well sleuthed. I agree with your sentiment (in your deleted post) that this is kind of annoying.

Comment: @Michael - Please explain why you think so.

Comment: Main reason is the following sentence from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html): "While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect."

Comment: Are you sure this is still true? There seems to be quite a few people thinking this is rather the "minimum thread pool size" and it should add threads as needed. Confusing....

Answer (score 6):

> *Does this mean that this ExecutorService implementation may create more than `corePoolSize` threads as needed?*

Yes, that is exactly what it means. The reason for the existence of `corePoolSize` is the expense of thread-creation. If you expect to be firing large numbers of short-lived tasks at your executor service, you may expect to find, at a given point in time, large numbers of *idle* threads.

Rather than have these threads die, only to be replaced a very short time later by newly-created threads, `corePoolSize` will ensure that there will always be a number of spinning threads.

Comment: The documentation! You either trust the documentation or you don't :-)

Comment: Well, looks like this is not actually true. Need to look at the documentation for `ScheduledExecutorService`, not just `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s `corePoolSize` concept. Now I'm wondering why it's not called `minimumPoolSize`...