# Why doesn't ScheduledExecutorService spawn threads as needed?

Tags: java

In my application I use ScheduledExecutorService, but only one thread is spawned to handle the scheduled tasks.  Is this because ScheduledExecutorService does not spawn threads to handle the pending tasks?

Here is a code snippet that will output only "run() 1" instead of the expected "run() 1" followed by "run() 2" ... "run() 10."

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 10;
        Runnable runner = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                foo();
            }
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            executor.schedule(runner, i, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    private static void foo() {
        System.out.println("run() " + (++n));
        synchronized (executor) {
            try {
                executor.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("finished()");
    }
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(App.class.getName());
    private static int n = 0;
    private static ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353002/why-does-scheduledthreadpoolexecutor-only-accept-a-fixed-number-of-threads

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42495659/how-to-create-a-scheduledexecutorservice-bound-by-only-the-cpu-usage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is only one thread because you create the thread pool with `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`, which means that the thread pool contains only 1 thread. If you want 10 threads, pass 10 as argument. Note that the documentation of [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html), which is what this method returns, explicitly says that the thread pool has a fixed size.

Comment: THANK YOU! 
My problem is with the documentation of **Executors**.newScheduledThreadPool(), which explicitly **does not** state this feature and the used variable name and the identical description everywhere suggests differently.

Answer (score 6):

From the javadoc for `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`:

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the
>   inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because
>   it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an
>   unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect.
>   Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to
>   zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool
>   without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

In other words, `maximumPoolSize == corePoolSize`. You set `corePoolSize` to `1`, so that's all it will spawn.